# Toggle viewstack within child component

Tags: apache-flex

I have a viewstack with two tabs.

In one of them there is a data grid shows a list of notes. The other one is includes a form that can edit notes or crates new note. I want the user to be able to add new note or edit existing note when clicks an item in data grid. I mean when user clicks an item the viewstack must become editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "selectedIndex" or "selectedItem" property on the viewstack to switch the active view. In your case, an event should be dispatched that bubbles up to the component containing the viewstack. When it arrives, the viewstack's active view can then be changed.